# Flutter Firestore could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I know about the answers that tell me how to download and install a plist file from the firebase console, but I want to configure the plugin to use my configuration in code, not in the plist file.

Is the a way to configure the flutter firestore plugin without plist but only through code?

TIA,
John

Comment: Perhaps changing the firebase SDK, to not look for the google-services.plist, and if successful, afterwards hardcoding your credentials in place where the SDK is looking for the `plist`. Also add to that, it's already hard(not sure if even possible currently) to add it without importing it through X-Code, not drag and drop as in android, so keep that in mind. But out of curiosity, why on earth?

Comment: Well we've built a shell for our apps, this package does code initialization of a generic firebase backend, so it uses the firebase flutter sdk (FlutterFire). The target app, the one that uses the appshell, does not require a firebase backend. This worked before but since a while, the target app now needs a .plist file because the shell uses these plugins... that makes no sense to me.. I want to keep the target app as clean as possible..